# htaccess redirect causing loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to

1. redirect domain.com -> www.domain.com
2. redirect www.domain.com -> www.domain.com/folder
3. redirect www.domain.com/folder -> www.domain.com/folder
4. redirect www.domain.com/folder2 -> www.domain.com/folder2

using htaccess redirect.

but I could only write the code for www part

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

could anybody help me with this?

Comment: I guess you mean fold -> folder1, folder1 -> folder2, folder2->folder3? This for sure looks like a loop yes.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have something else redirecting somewhere, the rules look fine except that you need a space between `domain\.com` and `[nc]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make one file per folder looking something like this.

domain.com root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

www.domain.com root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain.com/folder [R=301,NC,L]
```

folder `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?folder$ http://www.domain.com/folder1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I think you get the idea. Since I never done this myself I am not 100% sure if it will stop processing `.htaccess` files after the redirect is done. If not you will for sure end up in `folder2`.

**EDIT**: Added `L` since I missed it in my first version. Did some changes since I totally missed the first redirect step. I think the idea was still clear though. :)